# Positive definite matrix and it's eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Let $M$ be a positive definite matrix over complex field and let $\mu$ be its smallest eigenvalue. Is the matrix $M-\frac{\mu}{2}I$ positive definite? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a diagonal matrix $\;D\;$ with all its diagonal entries the given matrix's eigenvalues, and inversible $\;P\;$ such that

$$P^{-1}MP=D\implies P^{-1}\left(M-\frac\mu2I\right)P=D-\frac\mu2I$$

and since all the entries on the diagonal of $\;D-\frac\mu2I\;$ are positive, the matrix $\;M-\frac\mu2\;$ is positive definite.

Comment: Is it obvious that $M$ can be diagonalised?

Comment: @πr8 Of course it is: it is a symmetric matrix, which are the ones for which the notion of "positive definite" and etc. is defined, and any symmetric matrix is not only diagonalizable but even orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: Right, to me it wasn't clear that it was necessarily symmetric. Agreed on / aware of all other points.